Metadata time stamp - controlling precision?
I have recently upgraded from GeoNetwork 3.10 to 4.2.9
Previously, my records were time stamped to the nearest second. Now they are time stamped to three decimal places of a second. That's allowed, but it is giving problems with some "down stream" software that can't cope - and is maintained (reluctantly) by a different government department.
Is it possible to configure the precision with which records are time stamped? Or would I need to truncate / round the precision on export (in this case, to the old ISO 19139 XML format)?
